# Use Larave route to vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an `a` tag in one of my VueJS component like below.

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-white">
      <i class="tio-edit"></i>
 </a>
```

I would like to place `route('admin.shop.time.edit',1)` inside `href` with ID parameter.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can't you just write the API path, like, href="api_domain/admin/shop/time/edit/1"?

Comment: Thanks @NehaSoni. I am trying like this `<a href="/admin/shop/time/edit/{{ time.id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-white">
                                            <i class="tio-edit"></i>
                                        </a>`. But I am getting error. Thanks.

Comment: No, if route is starting from a ‘/‘ then it will be considered as the Vue route that’s why I wrote ‘api_domain/your rest path’. Try in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I use this package : https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

that provide a route() helper to use in javascript :

```js
route('user.profile')
```

you can define which routes are accessible from the js  in the config/ziggy.php file

```php
<?php
return [
    'whitelist' => [
        'user.*',
        'home',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'password.*',
    ],
];
```

You just have to put a `@routes` helper in your blade layout and it will work

it's iso with the laravel route helper, and can handle parameters and so on, like for example you can do `route('user.show', {id: '15'})`